# Tibco Designer integrate with TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tibco

Has anyone tried to integrate Tibco Designer especially for BusinessWorks with Team Foundation Server 2010?
At the moment, our Tibco designer is using VSS as its source safe control.
We are planning to migrate the VSS to TFS 2010 but I could not find a solution to integrate Tibco Designer with the TFS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I have no familiarity with the product directly, but since it is currently able to integrate with SourceSafe, perhaps the TFS 2010 MSSCCI provider might help?

You would install it on your client machine(s) so that application would be able to talk to TFS 2010 (and 2005/2008 with that version, it seems).  I have used the provider for getting Visual Studio 2003 to TFS 2010, which does not have native TFS support.

[Visual Studio Gallery Page for TFS 2010 MSSCCI Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6)

Comment: "MSSCCI provider" apparently provides backward compatibility only for legacy Microsoft's software IDE and not third party.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have integrated Designer with TFS in a retail project, but it does not leverage full strengths of a source control system. There are no auto builds, trunking. Just basic check-in check-out. For Designer SVN is a recommended source control system.

Comment: My intention is just to use TFS as the main repository rather than to fully utilize it.